# &nbsp Acting Oddly

Tags: xslt, encoding, html-entities

I'm seeing this odd issue where &nbsp is being turned into some odd "?" symbol. Like it's some unknown character I've typed. (I'm using &#160; in the xsl).

Once pass through the XSL just leaves this as &nbsp. Another "pass" through the XSL makes this odd character show up, the "?". The "?" even shows up when doing inspect element. So odd!

What could do the XSL transformer be doing to cause such a thing?

I've thought it was the different CSS templates being applied on the problem "pass" but the css I see through inspect element is identical for both cases.

Comment: The XSLT is not really relevant (or I can't post what is, job stuff :P)

Comment: I've just got <span> &#160; </span>

Comment: A small sample that actually produces your problem would be sufficient. You don't need to (neither should you) post your entire XSLT.

Comment: By your description the problem is not in the output result, but the browser interpretation. Do you correctly declare the encoding? `&#160;` or `&#xA0;` is the UNICODE encoding. If you use the `html` serialization method, you need to output a `head` element in order to auto `meta` addition takes place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon:

```
&nbsp;
```

Comment: In the title or in my code? I have a semicolon in the XSL.

Comment: In your question you said `&nbsp` without a semicolon, so I guess you haven't got it in your code either.